# nmcli creates new wifi profiles everytime I connect

Tags: networking, network-manager, nmcli

I am trying to connect to a wifi AP using this command -

```
nmcli device wifi con ap2ap_data iface wlan0
```

But every time I use this I can see new wifi profiles like ap2ap_data 1, ap2ap_data 2, ap2ap_data 3...etc. Please look at the image below.

[image]

How do I connect to ap2ap_data without creating new wifi profiles everytime?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this. Instead of using this command to disconnect

```
nmcli device disconnect iface ap2ap_data
```

I use

```
nmcli connection delete id ap2ap_data
```

This way it deletes the current profile before connecting again and creating a new profile.